# iTunes connect uploading video preview

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Why can't I upload my video preview for my app on iTunes connect?
I want to upload a video preview for my app on iTunes connect.
Note: I am running safari 9

Comment: Can you be more specific about what error message/response you are getting?

Comment: when I try to import the preview on iTunes connect, it thinks its a image and says it must be certain size. Is there a certain type of video file it must be to up-load it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apple is very restrictive with regard to the format of app preview videos. They have to be of a certain size, frame rate, etc. Please find the specification in the following page under "App Preview Properties":
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10

Comment: Well how do I change the resolution  on a video whats the best way\

Comment: One "official way" would be to use iMovie: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/imovie/Creating-App-Previews-with-iMovie.pdf

Comment: I think you can use video converters like "HandBrake" also